# Finding common values from Arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have 15 tables in database. All tables have one common row in it. For example every table have entry for "Robin_Ghosh", at least 13 tables have this value. Actually I have connected this with jframe in java and I want that user can only select 5 random tables and result of these 5 selected tables should come into jframe. From there every table should get loaded into array and then I will find out common values from this array using loop.

Anyone can help me to get out of this problem. Thanks in advance for your help. I am badly needed help of yours, because I am running out of time. I have to submit this into my collage.

Comment: Show us what you have done first.. we are here to help..

Answer (score 0):

You can use retainAll in collection framework

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(3);
        list1.add(5);
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();
        list2.add(1);
        list2.add(6);
        list2.add(7);
        list2.add(9);
        list2.add(3);
        List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList();
        list3.add(1);
        list3.add(3);
        list3.add(10);
        list3.add(11);

        List<Integer> addresses = new ArrayList();
        addresses.addAll(list1);
        addresses.retainAll(list2);
        addresses.retainAll(list3);
       System.out.println(addresses);
    }
```

Comment: Actually I am new in this field. Could you please tell me some more????